# Using HTTPS, can the target domain be seen?

Tags: tls, network, routing

If I go to `https://google.com/q=test_query` with from my browser, what traffic can be seen on the router?

Can the domain name (google.com) be seen?
If so, can I block all of the traffic to a web page by disallowing access to that domain? Does anything change if the website has multiple IPs (different servers)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can block by IP and by domain name. If the domain uses different IP addresses, and you block only one IP, the site will keep working with the other IP addresses. If you block the domain, and the site works by opening the IP address in the browser, it will keep working as well.

You can block domain names and IP addresses by port number. So you can block 443, and HTTPS is blocked for that domain, or IP, etc.

The router can see the domain when using HTTPS, but not the path and query.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a recent enough browser (mostly not ie on windows xp), it will likely have SNI support to allow virtual hosting of HTTPS sites.

This means that it will send the domain name unencrypted to allow the server to choose the correct certificate. Depending on what you use to filter traffic, you could thus block HTTP and HTTPS traffic to a specific domain by blacklisting the domains. Be aware though that a user with a browser not supporting SNI might be able to bypass this filter depending on your policy for requests without SNI.

If the website's IP (or IPs) do not change, it might be easier to filter based on IP address (but this us unlikely to be the case for Google). Filtering at IP level based on domain name is usually a bad idea as it implies either a DNS lookup at the beginning (e.g. iptables) which might not end up blocking the whole domain or reverse DNS lookups for every new IP (without even a guarantee that the reverse will match what you expect e.g. example.com could point to 203.0.113.1 which when reversed could point to server1.example.com or even server1.CDN.com). Some systems might however be able to do this based on intercepted DNS requests and responses.